# Liquibase labels

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

I was playing around with liquibase (SQL syntax) and got stuck with labels. I have them in my changelog, but the 'labels' column in the changelog table is empty. Because of that, I can't run any command where labels are involved.

I saw an example here: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/labels.html

What am I doing wrong ???

[image]

Thanks in advance )

Answer (score 1):

The doc appears to be wrong.  The changeset/changelog [example](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/labels.html) should be like the following:

```
--changeset Liquibase User:1 labels:1.0
create table primary_table (  
   id int primary key,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   address1 varchar(50),
   address2 varchar(50),
   city varchar(30)
)
```

Where **labels:1.0** key-value pair is on the same line where the --changeset tag is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped!